INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION in customer center client script on https.post() request - NetSuite SuiteScript
After recent 2024.16 update, we're getting "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION" in Customer Center's Client Script when https.post() request is made. Although, everything was working fine till few days earlier, but with the recent update, facing this error. Here's the simple code:
let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

let body = {
    "name": "Apple MacBook Pro 16",
    "data": {
        "year": 2019,
        "price": 1849.99,
        "CPU model": "Intel Core i9",
        "Hard disk size": "1 TB"
    }
} ;
let response = https.post({
    url: 'https://api.restful-api.dev/objects',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers:headers
});

Error Details
There's no explanation about what permission is missing? Besides, same code is working fine in Classic Center with Admin role. Has NetSuite discontinue to make https requests in client script? Or some other settings needs to be enabled in Role or Setup?
Looked into 2024.1 release notes, but found nothing.
Tried to look for new permission in Customer Center Role and also in SetUp -> Company -> Enable Features but found nothing.
